# Would You Capitalize a Part of Sentence That is After a Dialogue?

Tags: grammar, capitalization, quotations, dialogue

This something that I'm very confused about...
You see, here is one example of the sentence:

- I ran ahead and said, "I don't want that," and crashed against a wall.

In this sentence, you don't need to capitalize "and" even if there is a dialogue in-between because it's preceded with a comma, so it's still one sentence.

But what about this:

- The guy squished ahead, yelling, “Shut up and take my money!” Before throwing a handful of cash at another person.**

There is a "!" that  it's no longer a comma, so do you capitalize the next word or not?

Comment: The part following _before_ is not a new sentence, so it doesn't need a capital letter.

Comment: (1) You **don't** capitalise 'and' in your first example. It would be incorrect. But if you chose to use a full stop and a sentence fragment (care) you must capitalise the sentence fragment: << I ran ahead and said  "I don't want that." And crashed against a wall. >> (Note I prefer the option of zero rather than a comma introductory punctuation here. The inverted commas suffice to offset.) ////  (2) Here, you have a choice. If you want to consider the whole as a single sentence (as Kate does), the _non-capitalisation within a sentence_ rule trumps the _capitalisation after !/./?_ rule. ...

Comment: However, you can choose to treat  'Before throwing a handful of cash at another person.' as a sentence fragment, which requires the capital. This adds more of a staccato effect. It also puts up the hackles of ultra-traditionalists, who dislike any use of sentence fragments ... so be aware of your audience. Fragments beginning with 'before' are doubtless fairly rare in literature.

Comment: @KateBunting I see, I had thought so as well, but am not sure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry, what do you mean "option of zero" that you prefer, is it a period or null of any punctuation? But I see that I have an option here. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Sorry; I'll expand to clarify. 'I prefer the option of zero introductory punctuation rather than a comma [as] introductory punctuation here.' You might find answers at [Punctuating illustrating questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192120/punctuating-illustrating-questions/192227#192227) and [Can I use quotation marks to _suggest_ that somebody should say something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/can-i-use-quotation-marks-to-suggest-that-somebody-should-say-something/82829#82829) helpful.

Comment: ... [BusinessWriting](https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2008/08/quotation-marks.html) gives examples of zero punctuation before quotes that are not direct speech. [NUI Galway Marketing and Communications Office style Guide](https://www.nuigalway.ie/media/nuigalwayie/content/files/aboutus/Grammar,-Spelling-and-Punctuation.pdf) includes an example using direct speech: 'Obama said “This is a great day for Ireland.” '